# Batch to move folders that have a specific file in it

Tags: batch-file, directory, move

1. I am trying to get a list of folders that have a specific file `*.t` in it (there is not more than one such file in a folder):

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /B /A:-D /S "D:\Old\Stuff\*.t"') do 
   (@echo %%~dpa>>Folders.txt)

   endlocal
   ```

   This works and gives me a file with the full path and a `\` at the end...

   *e.g.

   D:\Old\Stuff\Folder 1\

   D:\Old\Stuff\Folder 2\

   D:\Old\Stuff\Folder 3\*
2. I then want to move said folders with it's contents to another location, but it's not working:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%i in (Folders.txt) do Move %%i "D:\New\Stuff\"
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't double quote `"%%I"` which is known to contain spaces from your file `Folders.txt`

Comment: Still not working... I think my _Move_ line is incorrect.

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from folder names

Comment: Do you mean from the results in the first script? How?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: There's no need to remove the trailing `\ `, simply append a `.` to the source directories. Have you considered what happens if a directory contains more than one `*.t` files, so it's contained multiple times in `Folders.txt`?

Comment: There will never be more that one *.t file within the folder.

Comment: @RaveWolf, I edited the question and mentioned that there are no duplicates possible, from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198564/batch-to-move-folders-that-have-a-specific-file-in-it#comment87416762_50198564), so the post is clear on its own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no duplicates possible, the solution is quite simple; you do not even need a temporary file `Folders.txt`:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /S /A:-D /B "D:\Old\Stuff\*.t"') do (
    move "%%~dpF." "D:\New\Stuff\"
)
```

`%%~dpF` returns the parent directory of each found `*.t` file with a trailing backslash. Just append a `.`, meaning the current directory, so the trailing `\` does no longer cause problems with the `move` command.

Do not attempt to remove the trailing backslash, because this could cause problems in some special situations: assume the target directory is `D:\`, so removing the `\` leaves `D:` which is not the same as `D:\` (but `D:\.` is).

Even in case there could be more than one `*.t` file in a certain directory, the code would work, although the `move` command threw an error for every duplicate, because the directory has already been moved before. Simply appending or prepending `2> nul` to the `move` command line hid those (and other) errors.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (Folders.txt) do Move "%%i*" "D:\New\Stuff\"
```

The first argument for `move` should be enclosed in quotes since the directorynames appear to contain spaces; The `*` specifies "all files in the directory".

You haven't said whether you want to move any subdirectories. You should note that move is designed for files, not directories.

Comment: As above, I have directories that have unique files in them with ext. " *.t ". I need to be able to move the folders (and everything within) that contain these files. 99% of the time it's just the folder with this file, hardly ever are there subfolders within this folder. If "Move" is for files only, then what is used for Folders?

Comment: This kinda worked, but only moved all the files into one folder and never recreated the individual folders.